# Structured Streaming Job stops abruptly

Tags: apache-spark

We have a structured streaming job which reads from kafka and does stateful association using mapGroupWithState API and then saves the resulting data frame to
a hdfs filesystem in parquet format. The job stops after running for a while. From the debug logs it looks like spark context is getting stopped which is leading to the query getting terminated.

18/05/14 06:34:54 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Following the above error message there are a bunch of exceptions caused because of the spark context being stopped.

Here is the memory limits assigned:
1 driver : 2GB
2 Executors: 2 cores each and 4GB

We are constantly monitoring the JVM memory usage using Graphite exporter. The memory usage on any of the application's JVM process never goes beyond 700MB.

Apart from the above error message rest of the exceptions seem to be trigger by sc being stopped.

Can anyone suggest the possible scenario that might lead to such error?

P.S: The job even exited while just writing to a console writer instead of parquet.

Comment: Did you ever find any solutions? We're facing the same problem right now...

Comment: First think to do would be to put logs to TRACE level. That should reveal some issues that were not printed in INFO level and give you some info about why context gets stopped.